# Reg: database is not starting up an error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

getting below error while starting the database:-

startup

```
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
ORA-01565: error in identifying file '+DATA/mis/PARAMETERFILE/spfile.276.967375255'
ORA-17503: ksfdopn:10 Failed to open file +DATA/mis/PARAMETERFILE/spfile.276.967375255
ORA-04031: unable to allocate 56 bytes of shared memory ("shared pool","unknown object","KKSSP^24","kglseshtSegs")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your database cannot find the SPFILE (newer init.ora) within ASM with the actual system parameters or has no permissions to access it.

Either your Grid Infrastructure stack or the dbs/spfile.ora is pointing to the wrong file.

To find out what the grid infrastructure stack is using, run "srvctl" which should display the parameterfile name the database should be using

```
srvctl config database -d <dbname>

...
Spfile: +DATA/<dbname>/PARAMETERFILE/spfile.269.1066152225
...
```

Then check (as the grid user), if the file indeed is not visible (by using asmcmd):

```
asmcmd
ASMCMD> ls +DATA/<dbname>/PARAMETERFILE/
spfile.269.1066152225
```

If the name is different, then you got the issue... (and you have to point to the correct file).

If the name is correct, then it could be wrong permissions on the oracle executable(s) (check My Oracle Support):

RAC Database Can't Start: ORA-01565, ORA-17503: ksfdopn:10 Failed to open file +DATA/BPBL/spfileBPBL.ora (Doc ID 2316088.1)

Comment: thanks, can you share the DOC ID 2316088.1

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share MOS Documents. You should get an official Oracle support account to access the knowledge library, which is excellent for dealing with Oracle databases. 
But I am sure you can find the correct Oracle executable permissions on other sites.